# Trouble to synchronise promises in Node.js using Q

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, sails.js, q

I am currently doing an API in Node.JS with the framework Sails.js. I am using promises for the first time and I have some troubles to sync my promises like I want.

My main function is the following :

```
createCard: function(req, res) {
    checkIfUserHasStripeAccount(req.user)
        .then(addCreditCardToStripeAccount())
        .then(function cardCreated() {
            res.send(200, {
                msg: 'Card created'
            });
        })
        .catch(function handleError(err) {
            res.send(err.httpCode, err.msg);
        })
},
```

Obviously I can't add a credit card to a stripe account if the user doesn't have one.

The function checkIfUserHasStripeAccount() checks if the account exists and if not, create it.

Here is the code for this part :

```
function checkIfUserHasStripeAccount(user) {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    if (!user.idStripe) {
        createStripeAccountToUser(user)
            .then(function(savedUser) {
                deferred.resolve(savedUser);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            })
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(user);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}

function createStripeAccountToUser(user) {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    var jsonUserToCreate = {
        description: user.firstname + ' ' + user.surname,
        email: user.email
    };

    stripe.customers.create(jsonUserToCreate, function(err, customer) {
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject({
                httpCode: 500,
                msg: 'some error'
            });
        } else {
            user.idStripe = customer.id;
            user.save(function(err, savedUser) {
                if (err) {
                    deferred.reject({
                        httpCode: 500,
                        msg: 'some error'
                    });
                }
                deferred.resolve(savedUser);
            });
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The problem is that the `.then(addCreditCardToStripeAccount())` is executed before `checkIfUserHasStripeAccount()` is finished.

I can't figure out why. I thought the `.then(addCreditCardToStripeAccount())` would only be executed if it received a reject or resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your line of thought.
The problem is that you are invoking your function instead of referencing it:

```
.then(addCreditCardToStripeAccount())
```

should be:

```
.then(addCreditCardToStripeAccount)
```

I expect this to work:

```
createCard: function (req, res) {
    checkIfUserHasStripeAccount(req.user)
    .then(addCreditCardToStripeAccount)
    .then(function cardCreated(){
        res.send(200, {msg: 'Card created'});
    })
    .catch(function handleError(err) {
        res.send(err.httpCode, err.msg);
    })
},
```

For future, note that the `()` after the function name invokes the function, as order of execution in JS will evaluate it first due to being inside the then's `()`.

In promise chains, always invoke only the first function. Example:

```
function first () { /*...*/ } // All return promise.
function second() { /*...*/ }
function third () { /*...*/ }

first() // Invoked
    .then(second) // Not invoked. second() will have been bad here.
    .then(third);
```

Comment: I tried what you told me to and it works. Thank you very much !

It creates another question though. I want my function addCreditCardToStripeAccount to take 2 parameters. I made a few experiments and it seems that the deferred.resolve() can only carry 1 argument. Is that correct ? Do I have to use a composite value like an object or an array instead ?

Comment: If you are using bluebird, you can use an array, and replace the `.then()` with a `.spread()`. I'm uncertain regarding native promises. I'm AFK, but I can help out in a bit. Glad to help. :)